# Java: Linked List containing a class

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I already made a circular LinkedList via nodal class, then I saw this LinkedList the `import.java.util.LinkedList` with operations add, addFirst and etc.

Using this, it could ease the burden traversing and accessing the LinkedList but my problem is, if I want to access the List and put some data in it? how?

```
public class stckoverflow {
    private int x;
    public void getx(int y){
        x = y;
    }
}

// then in the main we have
LinkedList<stckoverflow> ll = new LinkedList<>();
ll.add(0, ????? );
```

So the point is, if I want to access some functions/procedures in a specific class in the LinkedList, how can I do it? I have no problems accessing these things in the LinkedList via nodal class because I can simply say current gets head and then traverse via while loop until it ends.

I'm confused. Please help.

Comment: Classes start with uppercase in Java.

Comment: wanna add `new stckoverflow()` ?

Comment: That isn't true. But he should.

Comment: ll.add(new stckoverflow());

Comment: `public void getx(int y) { x = y; }` ???

Answer (score 0):

better obey Java naming convention, name your class as `Stackoverflow` or `StackOverflow`

```
Stackoverflow obj = new Stackoverflow();
//obj.set attributes if you have
// ...
ll.add( obj );
```